# Typedoc include doesn't work

Tags: typescript, typedoc

I am trying to use typedoc `include` so here is how I do that.

```
// ./src/store/index.ts

/**
 * [[include:TypeScriptReactReduxTutorial.md]]
 */

import { combineReducers } from 'redux'

import { counterReducer } from './counter/reducer'

import { IApplicationState } from './types'

/**
 *  Whenever an action is dispatched, Redux will update each top-level application state property
 * using the reducer with the matching name. It's important that the names match exactly, and that
 * the reducer acts on the corresponding IApplicationState property type.
 */
export const rootReducer = combineReducers<IApplicationState>({
  counter: counterReducer
})
```

and then run typedoc like this

`"create-docs": "typedoc --out ./doc/ ./src --externalPattern '**/node_modules/**' --ignoreCompilerErrors --includes 'mdDocs/'"`

But in the docs there is only added a line like this `Defined in store/rootReducer.ts:18` and no content from my markdown file. What am I missing in here?

Comment: If this hasn't been fixed yet, have you tried taking the single quotes off of mdDocs/ in your command, the way you have ./doc/ and ./src? I'm using a json file instead of command line params, but in mine I need to specify the --includes folder the same way I specify the --out folder. And at least in file mode,  TypeDoc parses and creates pages by the object (or enum, function, etc), not by the file. So it doesn't really have anywhere to put a comment standing by itself. I can't find good documentation for whether that's true in modules mode as yours defaults to be in though.

Comment: Correction: It doesn't seem to make a difference, a comment by itself doesn't appear anywhere in the generated documentation with either mode = modules or mode = file

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain if this is working all the way around.
This is working for me.

https://typedoc.org/api/

I am using TypeDoc 0.14.2

Here is my command line

```
typedoc --out docs ./src --includes ./doc
```

And here is an example of my comments

```
/**
 * Process contents and returns a the processed contents.
 * <div>&nbsp;</div>
 * <strong>See:</strong> {@link BuildProcess.buildInclude}
 * @param contents The contents of the file currently being read
 * @param srcpath The source path of the file that contents were read from
 * @param destpath The destination file that the contents are to be written into.
 * @returns The contents of the file after they have been processed.
 * [[include:usercase.md]]
 */
```

**Update 1**

It is also possible to include a directory and then include mardown files from subdirectories. For example my doc directory contains a directory named javascript_string.

```
typedoc --out docs ./src --includes ./doc
```

comments

```
/**
 * Process contents and returns a the processed contents.
 * <div>&nbsp;</div>
 * <strong>See:</strong> [[BuildProcess.buildInclude]]
 * @param contents The contents of the file currently being read
 * @param srcpath The source path of the file that contents were read from
 * @param destpath The destination file that the contents are to be written into.
 * @return The contents of the file after they have been processed.
 * [[include:javascript_string/usercase.md]]
 */
```